# Communication Between WebView and WebPage - Titanium Studio

Tags: titanium

I am working in a Mobile project (using Titanium Studio), in which i have the below situation

1) My Mobile app contacts Rails backend to check some data, say check validity of a 
   user id.

2) I found a way to load web pages in Mobile app, i.e., `WebView`

3) I could able to load the desired url, ex `http://www.mydomain.com/checkuser?uid=20121`
   which would return data like `status:success`

But i need to read this data to show whether the response from server is a success or failure, how do i achieve this?

**NOTE :** The above mentioned scenario is an usecase, but actually what happens is i load a third party url in `WebView` and when user enters the data and submits, the result will be posted back to my website url.

**EDIT :** So the process is like below

1) WebView loaded with third party url like `http://www.anyapiprovider.com/processdata`

2) User will enter set of data in this web page and submits the page

3) The submitted data will be processed by the apiprovider and it returns data to my web page say `http://www.mydomain.com/recievedata`

This is the reason why i am not directly using `GET` using `HTTPClient`
**FYI :** I tried to fire Ti.APP events right from the actual web page as suggested by few articles, but most of them says this will work only if the file loaded is in local and not a remote file. [Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685409/trouble-using-titaniums-webview-to-fire-an-api-event/9969336#9969336)

Please suggest me if my approach has to be improved.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to follow Josiah's advice, then take a look at the Titanium docs on how to add a `webview.addEventListener('load',...` event listener and use `webview.evalJS()` to inject your own code into the third party HTML.

Maybe you can inject code to trap the submit event and fire a Ti event to trigger the downloading of data from your website.

[Communication Between WebViews and Titanium - Remote Web Content Section](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Communication+Between+WebViews+and+Titanium)

Comment: TBH, I think you'll lose a lot of time trying to make it work with remote HTML... But also check this post [Trouble using Titanium's webview to fire an API event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685409/trouble-using-titaniums-webview-to-fire-an-api-event?lq=1)

Comment: Actually we could not trigger Ti.App event from a remote web page loaded in WebView.. it works only for local html..
I found a way for this.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for my problem

1) Load the `http://www.mydomain.com/checkuser?uid=20121` in a webview

2) Let user enter and submit data to third party url

3) Recieve the response from third party url and print only `<div id="result">status:success</div>` in `http://www.mydomain.com/recievedata` page.

4) Add event listener for the web view as follows

```
webView.addEventListener('load', function(data) 
{ 
   //Add condition to check if the loaded web page has any div with id = result (to check if this is /recievedata page)
    alert(webView.evalJS("document.getElementById('result').innerHTML"));
});
```

The above alert would print the result `status:success`, read it in webview load event
and take actions in web accordingly.

It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading it in a WebView why not just GET it using a HTTP Client? This is much cleaner, and more standards based:

```
var xhr_get = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload : function(e) {
        // Here is your "status:success" string
        var returnValue = this.responseText;
    },
    onerror : function(e) {
        Ti.API.info(this.responseText);
        Ti.API.info('CheckUserProgressOnActivity webservice failed with message : ' + e.error);
    }
});
xhr_get.open('GET', 'http://www.mydomain.com/checkuser?uid=20121');
xhr_get.send();
```

Comment: Actually in my project, i will load a third party url in webview first and when user enters data in the web page loaded and submits data, the results will be posted to my web page..  i have updated my question please see..